# Using two environment in Anaconda - issue with importing matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using two environments in Anaconda (Mac OS X). When I use Python 2.7 environment I can't import matplotlib:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It tells me that there is no module name like that.

I installed matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib`.  It installed successfully but then I opened Jupyter Notebook and I tried to import it  but still it doesn't work because there is no module name like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure matplotlib is installed in the env you've activated. If you need to use it in both envs, you need to install matplotlib into both envs.

Comment: Allen- I activated the 2.7 python environment and installed from there matplotlib, but stills does not work. You have any idea what else could be.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: Can you import matplotlib from python command line instead of jupyetr Notebook? Do you get the same error?

If you can import it from python command line, can you import it from iPython command line?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, can you please try the following once you've activated your env?

    pip install ipython

Comment: I am trying to import it from ipython command line but it does not work. From my terminal when type ls -a  I can see .matplotlib

Comment: I tried pip install python but it does not work.Should I reinstall python 2.7? Thanks!

Comment: please make sure you pip install ipython instead of python